# Paggination on api data in flutter

Tags: flutter, api, dart

i get data from API like  demo:-

```
{draw: 0, records Total: 210, records Filtered: 210, data: [,…], input: []}

data: [,…]
draw: 0
input: []
records Filtered: 210
records Total: 210
```

I want to apply paggination on API data (grid view or list view)

How can i do that ?

Answer (score 0):

Your json structure needs to look like this to apply pagination with ease.
Use `current page`, `next page` and `last page` to determine the next, current and remaining pages.

You can directly use the `next` link to get the data of the next page.

```
{
  "meta": {
    "page": {
      "current-page": 2,
      "per-page": 15,
      "from": 16,
      "to": 30,
      "total": 50,
      "last-page": 4
    }
  },
  "links": {
    "first": "http://localhost/api/v1/posts?page[number]=1&page[size]=15",
    "prev": "http://localhost/api/v1/posts?page[number]=1&page[size]=15",
    "next": "http://localhost/api/v1/posts?page[number]=3&page[size]=15",
    "last": "http://localhost/api/v1/posts?page[number]=4&page[size]=15"
  },
  "data": [...]
}
```